# Stopping auto upload to dropbox for specific folders

Tags: dropbox

From the dropbox android app you can select folders to monitor and auto upload to Camera Roll folder in dropbox. Now I selected other folders besides the camera photos (e.g. screenshots). How can I select again which folders to auto sync so I can remove some folders from the list? I do not seem to find it

Comment: Are you on Dropbox plus?

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) let's you chose what folders you want to sync with more options than Dropbox. It's very good - I have been using it for many years till I moved away from Dropbox recently. Only catch is free version let's you sync one folder whereas paid version can sync entire Dropbox

Comment: Use `rclone` if you don't mind CLI. Free, open-source and with a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @beeshyams yes I am

Comment: I only have free Dropbox so can't help with settings or how to. Anyway, you have a couple of alternatives proposed above

Comment: @beeshyams why use another app?

Comment: It's because I don't know how DropBox Plus works. Maybe some one who has that can answer